# Disable UIScrollView scrolling with second finger if already dragging

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I have `UIScrollView` with a `UIImageView`. The user is able to pan the image vertically.

How do I stop the user from continuing dragging with another finger, or ignore a second touch on the `scrollview`? Somewhat similar to the dragging behaviour in the photoBrowser of the Facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting both the canCancelContentTouches and delaysContentTouches properties of your UIScrollView to YES.

When the UIScrollView property canCancelContentTouches is set to YES, it should transfer any scrolling/drag touches to the scroll view and cancel whatever that touch would have been registered in the subview.

The scroll view's delaysContentTouches should be set to YES as well. This will prevent drags from being triggered as taps (because the handler fires off too soon).

and also try this link
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/06/hacking-uiscrollview-gesture-recognizers/